# strptime gives ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

there is file keeps data like this;

```
  hostname;2019-01-09T23:59:38Z ;2019-01-10T00:04:04Z
```

from this file I create new file like this; (in windows env.python 3.7)

```
  hostname;2019-01-09 23:59:38;2019-01-10 00:04:04;0:04:26
```

but I need to create same file in linux which python 2.7.5 installed.
there is a problem on the date field,I did not convert the seconds in date field.

Red-hat 7.5

Python 2.7.5

Error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
End2 =   datetime.strptime(End, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

And this is what I developed;

```
  #!/bin/python
  import datetime 
  import time


  with open(r"/root/backup/backup.txt") as f:
       with open(r"/root/backup/backup2.txt", 'w') as f1:
           for lines in f:

            fields = lines.split(";")
            Hostname = fields[0]
            Start = fields[1]
            End = fields[2]
            Start1 = datetime.strptime(Start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
            End2 =   datetime.strptime(End, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
            delta = End2 - Start1

            f1.write(Hostname + ";Start:"+str(Start1)+";Backup Finish:"+ str(End2)+";Backup Completed Time:"+ str(delta))

    f1.close()

  f.close()
```

what I expect the output is ;

hostname;2019-01-09 23:59:38;2019-01-10 00:04:04;0:04:26

Comment: When you print out `End`, what do you see?

Comment: The error occurs while you're processing `End`, so it would be useful to verify what `End` actually looks like. Add a `print(repr(End))` right after the `End = ...` line and verify that it's exactly what you're expecting.

Comment: Start=2019-01-10T00:00:41Z
End=2019-01-10T00:22:56Z
@glibdud

Comment: Did you use `repr()`? Because I'm pretty sure you'll find there's a trailing newline in `End`.

Comment: print(repr(Start)) it returns '2019-01-10T00:00:41Z'

Comment: @1010111100011: Verifying your **whole** setup, reading from file, I can reproduce your issue. You have **trailing** `blanks` and `\n`. Change to `fields = lines.rstrip().split(";")` and `fields[1].strip()`, `fields[2].strip()`

Comment: it works thank you @stovfl